# Filtrar objetos de un modelo según lista de palabras claves

Tags: python-3.x, django

Buenos días tengo el siguiente models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    id_news = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4) #
    title = models.CharField('Título de la Noticia',max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    news_website = models.ForeignKey(NewsWebsite, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    seccion = models.CharField('Sección', max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    texto_resumen = models.CharField('Resumen de la Noticia', max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField('Texto de la Noticia', blank=True, null=True)
    autor = models.CharField('Autor', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    tags = models.CharField('Tags', max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.URLField('URL de la Noticia', max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    estado_revision = models.CharField('Estado Noticia', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default='Pendiente') # este campo es para validar si ya esta procesado
    thumbnail = models.CharField('Url imagen',max_length=1000, blank=True)
    fecha_publicacion = models.CharField('Fecha Publicacion', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    fecha_modificacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    checker_runtime = models.ForeignKey(SchedulerRuntime, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class TipoDelito(models.Model):
    nombre_delito = models.CharField('Delito', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["nombre_delito"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre_delito

class DiccionarioDelito(models.Model):
    TipoDelito= models.ForeignKey(TipoDelito, on_delete=models.PROTECT,verbose_name='Tipo Delito',blank=False, null=False)
    Accion=models.CharField('Acción delito', max_length=100, blank=False, null=True)
    estadoTipoDelito=models.BooleanField(default=True,verbose_name='Estado Tipo Delito')
    fecha_registro = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    fecha_modificacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Diccionario Delito'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Diccionario Delitos'
        ordering = ["TipoDelito"]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.TipoDelito)+"-"+str(self.Accion)
```

y en mi admin.py tengo

```
    def get_queryset(self,request):
    dd = DicionarioDelito.objects.all()[0]
    accion = dd.Accion

    articulos_accion = Article.objects.filter(description__icontains = accion)
    return articulos_accion
```

Mi idea es poder filtrar el modelo Article en el campo description mediante un diccionario que se arma con el modelo DicionarioDelito en los campos TipoDelito y Accion, mi intención es que dichas palabras se busquen dentro de cada Article y me devuelva aquellos Articles que contengan alguna de esas palabras. les quedaría muy agradecido si me podrían dar por favor una mano con este tema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función que resuelve mi problema es

```
    def get_queryset(self,request):
    # Se genera el Diccionario
    keywords = DicionarioDelito.objects.values_list('TipoDelito__nombre_delito','Accion')

    # Filtramos las noticias por los tipos de delitos, acciones y estado
    q_objects = Q()

    for x,y in keywords:
        q_objects |= Q(description__icontains=x)
        queryset = Article.objects.filter(estado_revision='Pendiente').filter(q_objects)
    return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso mencionas que quieres encontrar todos los `Article` que calcen con un `tipoDelito` y `Accion`. Pero no especificas en detalle en donde hay que buscar estos valores. Dado la definición de  un `Article` asumo que quieres hacer una búsqueda dentro de alguno de sus campos de *charfield*, como no especificas asumiré que quieres buscar en el campo `description`, pero luego podrás generalizarlo al caso general.

El primer paso consistiría en obtener los valores relevantes para tu consulta. En este caso, sería conseguir el o los *String* de `Accion` que quieres identificar, y lo mismo con los `TipoDelito`.

Notar que `Accion` es un `charField`, y por consiguiente se mapea aun *string*. Y que `TipoDelito` es una llave foránea a un modelo que contiene un `charfield`, por lo que se puede obtener sus valores para filtrar.

Por lo que, para obtener los valores sería algo así:

```
dd = DiccionarioDelito.objects.all()[0]  # tomamos un diccionario de ejemplo
accion = dd.Accion  # contiene un string con la accion
tipo_delito = dd.TipoDelito.nombre_delito  # contiene un string con el tipo delito
```

Ahora teniendo estos valores, basta hacer uso del metodo `.filter` con el keyword `__contains` para preguntar por contenimiento:

```
articulos_accion = Article.objects.filter(description__contains = accion)  # conjunto de articulos que contiene en su campo description el string de la variable accion
articulos_tipodelito = Article.objects.filter(description__contains = tipo_delito)  # analogo al anterior
```

Esto lo puedes hacer para cada palabras que quieras buscar, si quieres buscar en varios campos puedes hacer, por ejemplo:

```
articulos_accion = Article.objects.filter(description__contains = accion, texto_resumen__contains = accion)
```

Finalmente puedes hacer la interseccion de estos conjuntos usando el operador & (and), para obtener el conjunto final de articulos relevantes:

```
articulos_relevantes = articulos_accion & articulos_tipodelito   #  puedes agregar operar mas conjuntos si deseas
```

Comment: Hola Vichoko muchas gracias por la mano que me estas dando con esta función, te cuento que implemente la función como me indicas, pero el filtro solo se está haciendo con la primera palabra que encuentra en el DiccionarioDelitos en el campo de Accion, actualice la función en mi modelo admin.py,

Comment: Vichoko mi idea es armar un diccionario con todos los delitos y acciones del modelo DiccionarioDelito y usarlo como criterio de filtro para devolver aquellos artículos que contengan un delito y su acción, no se si me explico bien.

Comment: No comprendo bien el criterio, podrías explicarlo en más detalle?